# Apply smile effect to face image in android application

Tags: java, android, image-processing, canvas, dlib

I am developing an android application which performs various operations on face image.

One of the feature is to apply smile effect on face using seekbar.

I am detecting the face using Dlib library which gives me the lips area points. Below is the reference.

[Reference image dlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaKz1.jpg)

Here is the code to detect lips using Dlib library.

```
final String targetPath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat";
if (!new File(targetPath).exists()) 
{
    FileUtils.copyFileFromRawToOthers(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks, targetPath);
}

FaceDet faceDet = new FaceDet(targetPath);
List<VisionDetRet> faceList = faceDet.detect(inputBitmap);

if (faceList.size() > 0)
{
    face = faceList.get(0);

    ArrayList<Point> facePointList = face.getFaceLandmarks();
    lipStartX = facePointList.get(48).x;
    lipStartY = facePointList.get(48).y;
    lipEndX = facePointList.get(54).x;
    lipEndY = facePointList.get(54).y;
}
```

After detecting the lips area I am unable to figure out how to apply smile effect and also modify it using seekbar. I tried with openCV library but it did not work for me.

This is an original image below.

[normal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOj1R.jpg)

Below is the result I want.

[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6uWV.jpg)

I want to know how can I achieve this result in android.

If anyone can help me or give me some guidance, it will be really helpful for me.